# using realloc in C with malloc

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I somewhat understand what realloc does but when trying to reallocate a certain size of memory doesn't seem to click in to my mind. What if there is not a contigious size of the size wanted. Or if null is passed in as the pointer or if the size passsed in was 0. I know that if the size is 0 then it wants to free that memory. 
Question:
using malloc with realloc?

```
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t newsize)
{
  if(newsize == 0)
    free(ptr);
  if(ptr == NULL)
    //does something
  //how does it malloc a size and copy everything over?
}
```

Comment: Did you try reading the `man` page for it? It explains all the scenarios you mentioned.

Comment: Did you read the documentation?  I think it explicitly answers all of your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (newsize == 0) {
    free(ptr);
    return;
}
if (ptr == NULL)
    return malloc(size);

// otherwise do a true realloc
```

As for

> What if there is not a contigious size of the size wanted.

Then `realloc` returns `NULL` and sets `errno` to indicate the error.

Comment: Once you malloced the size you want, how do you copy the data from the prev malloc to the new malloc? just a simple while loop?

Comment: @JamesCarter `memcpy()`. Did you know there's a wonderful search engine around called Google?

Comment: @JamesCarter or better yet `man` pages :P

Comment: Just a fair warning (that was in a deleted answer), be careful when using realloc when using existing memory, as you can lose the original data.  If you care about the possibility of low memory, you should instead use a malloc and check for a memory error first.

Comment: @Darthfett: you will never lose the existing buffer if you use `realloc` correctly, i.e. if you save the original pointer. There's no need to reinvent the wheel by doing your own `malloc`/`memcpy`/`free`.

Comment: @larsmans: Saving the original pointer is useful only if your low-memory recovery strategy does something other than aborting the program. Whether it makes sense to have such a strategy depends on the program.

Comment: @KeithThompson  Still, it's a very good idea to point out to people that a temporary ptr for realloc() is needed if you don't want to trash the original one if realloc() fails.  Whether or not they can/will handle such a condition safely is another issue.  But it's not obvious to most (apparently) that the interface is a bit "dangerous" if you don't consider the issue.

Comment: @KeithThompson: my point is that you never lose the original buffer. `realloc` doesn't touch it if it can't find enough memory to copy it into.

Comment: @larsmans: I agree completely. My point, supplemental to yours, is that if you're going to terminate the program on an allocation failure, it doesn't matter whether you lose the pointer to the original buffer. You need a fallback strategy if there are still things the program can do after a failure (say, continuing to process other things, or continue running with less memory). Novice programmers, as I presume the OP is, are not likely to run into such situations (yet!).